# Collectionviewsource filter methods

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I Follow MVVM model for my application, I have a textbox which acts as an input to filter the collection. I understood observablecollection filter using lambda expression but i couldn't understand collectionviewsource methods. how can i implement collectionviewsource methods using this.

Here is my viewmodel class:

```
private ObservableCollection<SPFetchCREntity> _CRmappings2 = new ObservableCollection<SPFetchCREntity>();
public ObservableCollection<SPFetchCREntity> CRmappings2
{
    get { return _CRmappings2; }
    set
    {
        _CRmappings2 = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("CRmappings2");
    }
}

public ICollectionView AllCRSP


{ get; private set;}



public void UpdatePopList()
{
   CRmappings2 = new ObservableCollection<SPFetchCREntity>(crentities.Where(p => p.MU_Identifier == selectmu.ToString()).ToList()); 
}
```

Comment: https://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html

Comment: @Mishka That a very good link, Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to the `ICollectionView` and filter this one:

```
public void UpdatePopList()
{
    CRmappings2 = new ObservableCollection<SPFetchCREntity>(crentities.ToList());
    AllCRSP = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(CRmappings2);
    AllCRSP.Filter = obj =>
    {
        SPFetchCREntity entity = obj as SPFetchCREntity;
        return entity != null && entity.MU_Identifier == selectmu.ToString();
    };
}

private string _selectmu;
public string Selectmu
{
    get { return _selectmu; }
    set { _selectmu = value; AllCRSP.Refresh(); } //<-- refresh the ICollectionView whenever the selectmu property gets set or when you want to refresh the filter
}
```

Comment: I am getting error near `obj.MU_Identifier` , definiton doesn't exist. When i checked intellisense its showing me only four options like Equals,Hashcode,GetType,ToString. The entity properties are not shown

Comment: Sorry, it should be entity.MU_Identifier. Answer edited.

Comment: Yes this worked, and in XAML i should use ALLCRSP to bind it ?

Comment: Yes, you should bind to the ICollectionView that you filter.